# The column name contains space in its name. How do I pass it in propertyname of WFS call in geoserver?

Tags: whitespace, geoserver, getfeatureinfo

I have the following url:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=anjali%3Aaddress&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&isDenormalized=false&propertyname=housenumber,housename,poi,street,subsublocality,sublocality,locality,village,subdistrict,district,city,state,pincode,formattedaddress,eloc,latitude,longitude,geocodelevel,confidencescore,id,fulladdress ,lat&count=500&startIndex=0
```

Here fulladress contains a space after it i.e. 'fulladdress ' which I'm passing in the propertyname while making a wfs request via geoserver. I'm getting the following error from geoserver:

> <ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://localhost:8081/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">
> <ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="GetFeature">
> ows:ExceptionTextRequested property: fulladdress is not available for anjali:address. The possible propertyName values are: [geom, housenumber, housename, poi, street, subsublocality, sublocality, locality, village, subdistrict, district, city, state, pincode, formattedaddress, eloc, latitude, longitude, geocodelevel, confidencescore, id, fulladdress , lat]</ows:ExceptionText>
> </ows:Exception>
> </ows:ExceptionReport>

I have tried the following but nothing seems to work:

1. Replacing space with %20
2. Repacing fulladress with 'fulladdress '
3. Repacing fulladress with "fulladdress "

I have even read the official documentation regarding this but nothing is mentioned regarding this issue.
Also if I remove the whitespace then the information regarding fulladdress is not returned by the geoserver.
A prompt help will be much appreciated.

Comment: tip: make your life easy and remove this trailing white space at the source

Comment: That's in the problem statement that I can't remove the trailing white spaces from the source.

Comment: no, this question is about a wfs request, I am talking about the layer setup, its underlying data source, so when it was added to Geoserver or maybe even before that, when then dataset was created

Comment: have you tried + instead of %20?

Comment: I tried using + as well, the error is still the same.

Comment: I cannot manipulate the dataset, so that's not an option as of now.

Comment: I would try url-encoding the entire request or switch to POST request - but fixing the name is way easier